# What is 'id' in the following code? in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, class, pointers

I want to ask that what is that id? I don't understand what this id is. I got this code from a book and it says a generic type that's used to refer to any kind of object. Can anyone help me with this? I read it few times. Still can't get it.

```
void drawShapes (id shapes[], int count){

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        id shape = shapes[i];
        [shape draw];
    }

} // drawShapes
```

Comment: Which book, by the way? I'm not sure I approve of writing Objective-C in C style like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`id` is an alias for an unknown Objective-C object. It can be used to declare any Objective-C object value.

In the example you have it is using an `id` rather than a specific class so that the code is not dependent on the class of shape.

Comment: @Abizem, 

I still dont get the idea. Can you give an example?

Answer (score 4):

Strictly speaking `id` is defined as a pointer to an `objc_object` struct.

```
typedef struct objc_object {
    Class isa;
} *id;
```

In practical terms this means *any Objective-C object*.

However don't confuse this with `NSObject *`. While in many cases the equivalence may hold, there are classes which do not descend from `NSObject` but are still valid Objective-C objects (and therefore whose type can be `id`). One notable example is `NSProxy`.

Answer (score 1):

In the code you posted, the *id* stands for the type of items that will be stored in a C static Array. In particular, the *id* type indicates any Objective-C object.

Anyway, I would not recommend to use C static arrays in Objective-C to contains objects of unknown type, when you can achieve the same result by using an instance of NSArray.

Answer (score 0):

id means "a reference to some random Objective-C object of unknown class"  an example is when you make an at property for a uibutton sometimes it will come up as id but setting it as uibutton will help xcode fill in blanks for you while your typing because now xcode knows exactly what this object is. in your situation shape could be a string or a number or something else if you were just looking at that line of code though passing anything into it could give another line a error later on.